# For integers, when should I use BFV / BGV / CKKS / TFHE?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

When performing homomorphically encrypted computations, when should I use BFV / BGV / CKKS?

It seems BFV / BGV is better suited for integers, and CKKS for floats. It also seems BFV-BGV have some portability. I want to calculate using integers.

How do I understand if I should use BFV or BGV?

I also don't understand why the imprecision from CKKS could not simply be fixed by rounding, since it is comparatively small.

EDIT:As suggested below, another option could be TFHE.
EDIT II: I've implemented BFV, BGV, and CKKS from [scratch in R](https://github.com/bquast/HomomorphicEncryption), given how similar CKKS is to BFV, it is really not clear why one is suited for interget and the other for float

Comment: @kelalaka I would like to calculate integers, so I'm not sure about BFV or BGV. I also don't understand why the impression from CKKS could not simply be fixed by rounding, since it is comparatively small. Does that clarify?

Comment: @kelalaka, thank you, good point. Done